# IE7 & Validation: Why doesn't this work?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, jquery-validate

Here is my HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#formTest").validate({
            rules: {
                Test: { required: true, digits: true }
            }
        });
    });

</script>
<h2>
    Index</h2>
<form action="#" method="post" id="formTest">
    <input type="text" name="Test" id="Test" />
    <input type="submit" value="Test" />
</form>
```

With Chrome, when I click on the submit button, the submit is cancelled and the message **This field is required.** is displayed.

But in IE7, this doesn't work. When I click on the submit button... the form is submitted and no validation... :(

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Isn't it likely to be because MSIE 7 doesn't follow the standards as closely as newer browsers (such as MSIE 8 or 9, or Firefox, Chrome, Opera, etc)?  It is exactly the sort of thing that makes web programmers tear their hair out.

Comment: The code works perfectly for me in IE 7 hey.  Maybe you need to paste more code?

Comment: @khoomeister, no more code. I just have this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my code and it works perfectly.  I'm using the latest version of jquery validate.

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#formTest").validate({
            rules: {
                Test: { required: true, digits: true }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<h2>Index</h2>
<form action="#" method="post" id="formTest">
    <input type="text" name="Test" id="Test" />
    <input type="submit" value="Test" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: WoW, I'm using jQuery validate 1.6 and I'm just seeing the latest version is 1.8.1!!! I will try!

Comment: hi - which version of jquery.validate was this?